# while creating a audit trigger throwing warning as Compilation error

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I try to create a audit trigger it throwing compilation error.

could you please help me for creating trigger..

```
DROP TRIGGER DB.DAT_CAMPLE_REQ_Test;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER DB."DAT_CAMPLE_REQ_Test"
AFTER insert or update or delete on DAT_CAMPLE_REQ
FOR EACH ROW  
declare
  dmltype varchar2(6);
BEGIN
  if deleting then

    INSERT INTO h_dat_cample_req VALUES     (       
      :Old.REQUEST_ID,      
      :Old.SAMPLE_ID,      
      :Old.CASSAY_ID,       
      :Old.CASCADE_ID,       
      :Old.STATUS_ID,       
      :Old.AUTHOR,       
      :Old.CRT_SAE,       
      :Old.SCREEN_SAE
    ); 

  else

    if inserting then   

      dmltype := 'insert';  

    elsif updating then 

      dmltype := 'update';   

    end if;  

    INSERT INTO h_dat_cample_req VALUES
    (
      :New.REQUEST_ID,  
      :New.SAMPLE_ID,  
      :New.CASSAY_ID,  
      :New.CASCADE_ID, 
      :New.STATUS_ID,  
      :New.AUTHOR,   
      :New.CRT_SAE,     
      :New.SCREEN_SAE 
     ); 

  end if; 

END;
```

Comment: The error you are getting would be a big help.

Comment: Trigger created with compilation error... this is wat i getting......

Comment: To see the errors, type: `SHOW ERRORS TRIGGER DB.DAT_CAMPLE_REQ_Test`

Comment: Warning: compiled but with compilation errors... This warning i m getting... and also using Show Errors its returning no errors

Comment: Can any1 suggest me how to crete this trigger...

Comment: Edit and add table `h_dat_cample_req` structure

Comment: If TonyAndrews' hint didn't help, try `SHOW ERRORS TRIGGER DB."DAT_CAMPLE_REQ_Test"` - note the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided the exact error message nor the structure of the table `h_dat_cample_req`, so I'm afraid I'm going to have to guess.

I suspect the column names in your `h_dat_cample_req` are not in the order you expect, or there are other columns in the table that you haven't specified a value for in your `INSERT` statements.

You are using `INSERT` statements without listing the columns that each value should go in to.  The problem with using this form of `INSERT` statement is that if the columns in the table aren't in exactly the order you think they are, or there are columns that have been added or removed, you'll get an error and it'll be difficult to track it down.  Furthermore, if you don't get a compilation error there's still the chance that data will be inserted into the wrong columns.  Naming the columns makes it clear which value goes in which column, makes it easier to identify columns that have been removed, and also means that you don't have to specify values for all of the columns in the table - any column not listed gets a `NULL` value.

I would strongly recommend always naming columns in `INSERT` statements.  In other words, instead of writing

```
INSERT INTO some_table VALUES (value_1, value_2, ...);
```

write

```
INSERT INTO some_table (column_1, column_2, ...) VALUES (value_1, value_2, ...);
```

Incidentally, you're assigning a value to your variable `dmltype` but you're not using its value anywhere.  This won't cause a compilation error, but it is a sign that your trigger might not be doing quite what you would expect it to.  Perhaps your `h_dat_cample_req` table is a history table and has a column for the type of operation performed?